# Can I make my iphone app use only a portion of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I was hoping to create a small windowed screen when the home button is pressed. It would keep a portion of the app process open while another app isn't open.

So say I had music playing on the app and when the home button gets pressed the screen would be windowed or shrunk and just displayed over the main screen (kind of like the little help button that can be moved around). Would using widgets in IOS 8 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user presses the Home button, the app goes to background, and that's it. You can't customize that action.

You only get a notification that the user closed the app so that you can save your app state or data for the next launch.